# How do I pause Macro until either print or back is selected in Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PrintPreviewAndPrint")

Tags: excel, printing, print-preview, vba

I have a user form that selects sheets to print and then prints them once a command button is clicked.

I want to open the "Backstage" PrintPreviewandPrint page to allow for simultaneous selection of printer properties and preview the selected sheet for printing. Once I have clicked print, or the back arrow, I want to PrintPreviewandPrint page to close and select "Home" screen.

When I use

Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PrintPreviewAndPrint")

the desired screen is displayed, but the macro continues to run and the print preview show the home screen. i.e. the macro does not wait for an input from the PrintPreviewandPrint page before continuing.

Code is

```
Private Sub PrintDoc()

Sheets("Doc").Select
Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PrintPreviewAndPrint")
Sheets("Home").Select
End Sub
```

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: Perhaps using Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrintPreview).Show works better? Not the same, but at least it waits until you exit print preview.

Comment: I tried using PrintPreview but found that I wanted the option to change printer settings. I was wondering what event I could use to trigger selection of the Home page.

Answer (score 1):

- Remove the Sheets("Home").Select
- Add a routine in the module containing your PrintDoc:

  ```
  Sub AfterPrint()
      Sheets("Home").Select
  End Sub
  ```
- put this in your ThisWorkbook module

  ```
  Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)
      Application.OnTime Now, "AfterPrint"
  End Sub
  ```

Comment: This works if the user decides to print, but when the back arrow is selected, the "Doc" sheet is still active. Trying to figure out what the event is for the back arrow so I can trigger "Home" page when it is clicked.

Comment: I'm afraid there is no event that gets triggered, it is like cancelling out of a menu.

Answer (score 1):

I found a slightly messy solution...

First I call the print preview with:

```
Sub Printdoc()

    Sheets("Doc").PrintPreview
    Sheets("Home").Select

End Sub
```

Then I call the Print Dialogue if print is selected

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)

    Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrint).Show

End Sub
```

Either way(Print or Cancel), the PrintDoc macro completes by displaying the "Home" screen